# Adi program with openmp

Tags: c, openmp

This is my first post here so sorry if I make an easy/silly question. I have an assignment for my parallel programming class.I need some programs to be parallelized. So my problem is the following; I can't parallelize all sections of the program. If I parallelize 2 blocks of `for`, the results are not the same with the serial results. So here is the program

```
#pragma scop
 for (t = 0; t < _PB_TSTEPS; t++)
    {
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) shared(X,B,A)  private(i1,i2) 
      for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    for (i2 = 1; i2 < _PB_N; i2++)
      {
        X[i1][i2] = X[i1][i2] - X[i1][i2-1] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1][i2-1];
        B[i1][i2] = B[i1][i2] - A[i1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1][i2-1];
      }
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) shared(X,B)  private(i1)
      for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    X[i1][_PB_N-1] = X[i1][_PB_N-1] / B[i1][_PB_N-1];
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) shared(X,B,A)  private(i1,i2) 
      for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N-2; i2++)
      X[i1][_PB_N-i2-2] = (X[i1][_PB_N-2-i2] - X[i1][_PB_N-2-i2-1] * A[i1][_PB_N-i2-3]) / B[i1][_PB_N-3-i2];

      for (i1 = 1; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++) {
      X[i1][i2] = X[i1][i2] - X[i1-1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
      B[i1][i2] = B[i1][i2] - A[i1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
    } 
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) shared(X,B)  private(i2)
      for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++)
    X[_PB_N-1][i2] = X[_PB_N-1][i2] / B[_PB_N-1][i2];

      for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N-2; i1++)
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++)
      X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] = (X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] - X[_PB_N-i1-3][i2] * A[_PB_N-3-i1][i2]) / B[_PB_N-2-i1][i2];
    }
#pragma endscop
```

I have to parallelize this section of the code and I can't figure out how to parallelize the last 2 `for` and the 2 other `for` above.I have tried approximately the same openmp code with the other `for`'s. Below are the two blocks of `for`'s that I have problem.

```
  for (i1 = 1; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++) {
      X[i1][i2] = X[i1][i2] - X[i1-1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
      B[i1][i2] = B[i1][i2] - A[i1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
    } 



for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N-2; i1++)
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++)
      X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] = (X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] - X[_PB_N-i1-3][i2] * A[_PB_N-3-i1][i2]) / B[_PB_N-2-i1][i2];
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

See all code here,

https://github.com/fedon99/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/adi.c

Comment: Fix the code formatting so it's easier for us to read.

Comment: hi there , and thanks for your quick response i post a github link so you can see it better https://github.com/fedon99/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/adi.c

Comment: Hello, Welcome on StackOverflow, don't use links elsewhere, every necessary code must be within the question. Also, try to improve your written English. Start sentences with capital letters, capitalize "I", use apostrophes in "can`t". Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, sorry for my English I try to do my best, I fix some mistakes and I try to show you exactly where is my problem. Is it better now?
Thank you again.

Comment: Parallelize the inner loops over `i2`.

Comment: Wha't's an Adi program?

Comment: Is from polyBench files

adi Alternating Direction Implicit solver 

http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~pouchet/software/polybench/

Comment: That's not important for the title of your question. You should change the title to say something about your problem (which in this case in a dependency between iteration in one loop).

Comment: Ok thanks for the note I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of the rows depend on other rows so you can't parallelize that easily. However, the columns don't depend on other columns so you can parallelize the inner loop like this:

```
for (i1 = 1; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++) {
      X[i1][i2] = X[i1][i2] - X[i1-1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
      B[i1][i2] = B[i1][i2] - A[i1][i2] * A[i1][i2] / B[i1-1][i2];
    }
} 

for (i1 = 0; i1 < _PB_N-2; i1++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++) {
        X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] = (X[_PB_N-2-i1][i2] - X[_PB_N-i1-3][i2] * A[_PB_N3-i1][i2]) / B[_PB_N-2-i1][i2];
    }
}
```

As long as `_PB_N >> nthreads` this should work fine.

You could also swap the order of the loops like this

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i1)
for (i2 = 0; i2 < _PB_N; i2++) {
    for (i1 = 1; i1 < _PB_N; i1++)
```

however this will be cache unfriendly.

Also, I don't see any reason to use dynamic scheduling. Static scheduling should be more efficient. If you don't specify  the scheduling (like in my code above) the de facto default is static.

Comment: I will test it  and I will response to you thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very the program now runs very quickly with 8 threads :)

Thank you again :)

Comment: Since this looks like homework I would suggest swapping the order of the loops and testing the performance so that you learn about bad cache usage.

Comment: Hi again, I use the swapping that you said but I get the segmentation fault. :(

Comment: @FedonPat, I don't know why you get a segmentation fault when swapping. Debug it (you don't need anything more than `printf` to debug it). In any case swapping will give bad performance.